# "prior to studying" or "prior to study"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I am currently a sophomore year student in Computer Science at the university and i want to start writing my CV.

I want to mention in the introduction to my CV that I was once a QA at several Hi-Tech companies and I am debating how to write it in proper English.

> "Prior to study at the academy I worked as a QA at several Hi-Tech companies from 2015-2018"

or

> "Prior to my study at the academy I worked as a QA at several Hi-Tech companies from 2015-2018"

or

> "Prior to studying at the academy I worked as a QA at several Hi-Tech companies from 2015-2018"

Comment: You could say: Prior to pursuing my Bachelor's degree in Computer Science at the University of [...], I worked as a QA at several Hi-Tech companies from 2015-2018. I would say that avoid the use of "several" - either use the total number of companies you worked for or don't say anything on this at all. Your resume section on Work Experience will show the names.

Comment: Also, is "Hi-Tech" a commonly used term in resumes in your field? I know we use it daily when we talk, but I suspect this might not be suitable for a resume. Why not say "reputable companies"? I am not sure though if it is something widely used or not.

Comment: You are right, mistakenly i wrote resume, when in fact i meant i want to write that paragraph in the introduction to my resume. thank you for your help

Comment: Do you mean Cover Letter or the "Professional Summary / Personal Statement / Career Objective" introduction part in a resume?

Comment: Proper English 101: please pay attention to sentence case and spelling. Always capitalize "I".

Comment: @AIQ yes, thats what i meant - cover letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Prior to study", "Prior to my study", "Prior to studying" all are reasonable ways of expressing this.  As has been indicated in comments, using "several..." is rather weak (use the actual number or nothing). "Hi-Tech" looks odd ("technology companies" would be better) and since you can give details of dates in the actual CV, so "2015-2018" is not needed.

Of greater concern (and what would get your CV ignored straight away) is that you are making little or no attempt to use capital letters correctly. "I" and "I'm" should always have a capital. "Hi-Tech" shouldn't have capitals unless it starts a sentence.